# Dates doesnt show up in the bibliography (Using zotero and IEEE)

Tags: bibliographies, date, zotero

As the title says, the dates don't show up in the bibliography. Currently referencing in IEEE style and using Zotero as a reference library. When checking the references.bib the dates are all there. Even tried with different reference styles, but to no avail. Some of the codes i have used:

```
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{natbib}

Bla bla some text
\cite{hofstad_prototyp_2019}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references}
```

I have also tried using

```
\citep{hofstad_prototyp_2019}
```

and

```
\parencite{hofstad_prototyp_2019}
```

In the main text, the reference shows up as [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx2Mj.png) (as it should), but the dates at the end of the document dont show up, as seen in this picture. Access date is also not present.

[image: No dates shown]

Feel like I've tried every possible solution, even using a .bst file with a reference template.

Not that good with Latex, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Could you make your code compilable and provide the `.bib` entry so that we can help you?

Comment: Will definitely need the .bib, but one thing to check is that you're using BibTeX (and not BibLaTeX) from Zotero. The two formats store dates differently.